# Groups and their floor - MySQL joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table of groups ("Programmers", "Designers", "HR", etc) and a corresponding ID.
I also have a table of employees. Each employee belong to a group.
In the employees table, I have a floor field - which indicates on which floor they are at.

Both the employees table groups table are expected to remain unchanged during this year.

I want to add a new field to the groups table called "constant_floor". If all employees in a group are in the same floor, it will be the number of the floor. otherwise it will be 0.

Any ideas on how to achieve that efficiently? I have about 50,000 rows in my employees table and 10,000 different groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you want to achieve :

```
  update 
    groups g 
      left join
    (select floor_no, group_id, count(distinct floor_no) 
       from employees group by group_id having count(distinct floor_no) = 1) temp
      on g.id = temp.group_id
  set g.constant_floor = ifnull(temp.floor_no, 0);
```

I am assuming that you have an `index` on `group_id` in the `employees table` (perhaps via a `foreign_key` relation). If you don't have, I would recommend to create one). The `update` query should not take a lot of time, then.

Also, perhaps you could create a temporary `index` on `floor_no` in the `employees table` and remove it after the `update`.

sqlFiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9866/1

Comment: Thank you! It works.

SQLFiddle also looks like a neat tool, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Indeed, it is. I was also quite pleased to see it for the first time when someone had created a sqlfiddle for an answer on SO.